# How to override Handlebars' `if` helper

Tags: handlebars.js, mandrill

I'm looking for a way to change how Handlebars' `if` helper works.

Mandrill has made [a few modifications](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content#additions-to-standard-handlebars#additions-to-standard-handlebars) to the standard Handlebars. One of these handy changes is in the way they handle Handlebars' `if` block helper. They've added the ability to evaluate expressions inside the `if` helper like this:
`` {{#if `purchases > 3`}} ``

I need to be able to compile Mandrill templates locally, for testing and preview, and this feature is making it difficult. I know I can write my own custom helpers, but in this case I'm looking for a way to alter the way the built-in `if` helper works.

I guess I could build my own version of Handlebars.
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a problem to redefine the standard helpers as long as yours are working fine. You'll find in the below snippet one example that override the if helper to put instead a text. So just register your own helper this will override the default one. If you want the {{else}} also working you'll have to handle it in your if helper code.

```js
 
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = {
    "textexample1" : "hello",
  };
  Handlebars.registerHelper('if', function(text) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(text);
  });
 var source   = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html    = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#if 'test override'}}
   {{textexample1}}
{{/if}}
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```